# Entity Framework relationship to tables which use SQL Server SEQUENCE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables `House` and `Car`. Their primary keys come from SQL Server sequences.

I have a third table `Images` where images are stored. Table `Images` also has field `stuff_id` which is related to primary key in `House` and `Car` tables (so I know which house or car is on the picture). Every house could have multiple images, and also each car could have multiple images.

The question is how to make this work in Entity Framework, so I can get images as collection of specific `House` or `Car` object?

Usually I add relationship in SQL Server, but in this case the relationship should be one to many relationship between `Images` table on one side and two tables (`House` and `Car`) on the other side...

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this without changing the design. And, carrying just the ID on the Images table won't be enough; you also need a IdType column to identify the table StuffId belongs to.  I'd recommend carrying HouseId and CarId on the Images table. That will make the EF configuration pretty standard.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I don't need IdType because ID is unique across House and Car tables (it comes from SEQUENCE object). Adding HouseId and CarId is last resort :). It just doesn't look elegant.

Comment: A foreign key column (like `stuff_id`) ***cannot*** reference two different tables - referencing `House` once, and `Car` some other time. That just isn't feasible. What you need are **two** foreign keys - one for `House`, and one for `Car` - and possibly code to prevent both from having values at the same time.

Comment: That you had to call it "stuff_id" should be a red flag. Go with the straightforward designs suggested and the next programmer that uses your code will thank you - or at least not curse you :)

Comment: Yes, but :), what if I get more tables, e.g. Children, Bike, Pet etc., I can't add then fields in Image table: children_id, bike_id, pet_id etc. What if there is a 100 tables? To place 100 id columns? Must be a better way.

Comment: If that's the case, separate the relationship from Image. Assuming each object can have multiple images, create tables for HouseImage (with HouseId and ImageId), CarImage (with CarId and ImageId) and so on. This will give you simple queries, and flexibility with the relationship.